Issue with Chrome Offscreen Document Context in Service Worker
I'm currently working on a Chrome extension where I need to process multiple HTML contents using an offscreen document in the service worker. The aim is to ensure that each HTML content is parsed and processed correctly. However, I am encountering an issue where the chrome.runtime.getContexts method returns an empty array, even though the offscreen document appears to be created and functioning properly.
background.js
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

const OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT_PATH = '/offscreen.html';

let creating; // A global promise to avoid concurrency issues

async function setupOffscreenDocument(path) {
  const offscreenUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL(path);
  const existingContexts = await chrome.runtime.getContexts({
    contextTypes: ['OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT'],
    documentUrls: [offscreenUrl]
  });
  console.log("existingContexts", existingContexts);
  if (existingContexts.length > 0) {
    console.log('Offscreen document already exists.');
    return;
  }

  if (creating) {
    await creating;
  } else {
    console.log("creating offscreen document");
    creating = chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
      url: path,
      reasons: [chrome.offscreen.Reason.DOM_PARSER],
      justification: 'Parse DOM'
    });
    await creating;
    creating = null;
    let contexts = await chrome.runtime.getContexts({
    contextTypes: ['OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT'],
    documentUrls: [offscreenUrl]
  });
  console.log("contexts after create:", contexts);
  }
}

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
  await setupOffscreenDocument(OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT_PATH);

  // Array of HTML contents
  const htmlContents = [
    '<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World 1</h1></body></html>',
    // '<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World 2</h1></body></html>',
    // '<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World 3</h1></body></html>',
    // '<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World 4</h1></body></html>',
    // '<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World 5</h1></body></html>'
  ];

  // Send each HTML content to offscreen document
  const processingPromises = [];
  for (const htmlContent of htmlContents) {
    processingPromises.push(sendMessageToOffscreenDocument('add-exclamationmarks-to-headings', htmlContent)
      .then(() => console.log("parsed htmlcontent:", htmlContent))
      .catch(error => console.error('Failed to process HTML content:', error)));
  }
  console.log('All HTML contents processed.');
  Promise.all(processingPromises).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  }).catch(error => console.log(`Error in promises ${error}`));

 
  await closeOffscreenDocument();
});

async function sendMessageToOffscreenDocument(type, data) {
  const messageId = generateUUID();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const messageHandler = (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
      if (message.type === 'add-exclamationmarks-result' && message.id === messageId) {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(messageHandler);
        resolve(message.result);
      }
    };

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messageHandler);

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      type,
      target: 'offscreen',
      data,
      id: messageId
    });
    console.log("sended message to offscreen: ",type, data, messageId)
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessages);

async function handleMessages(message) {
  if (message.target !== 'background') {
    return;
  }

  switch (message.type) {
    case 'add-exclamationmarks-result':
      handleAddExclamationMarkResult(message.data);
      break;
    default:
      console.warn(`Unexpected message type received: '${message.type}'.`);
  }
}

async function handleAddExclamationMarkResult(dom) {
  console.log('Received dom', dom);
}

async function closeOffscreenDocument() {
  
  if (!(await hasOffscreenDocument())) {
    console.log("no offscreen document to close ")
    return;
  }
  console.log("closing offscreen document")
  await chrome.offscreen.closeDocument();
  console.log("closed offscreen document");
}

async function hasOffscreenDocument() {
  console.log("checking offscreen document")
  if ('getContexts' in chrome.runtime) {
    const contexts = await chrome.runtime.getContexts({
      contextTypes: ['OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT'],
      documentUrls: [OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT_PATH]
    });
    console.log("contexts", contexts)
    return Boolean(contexts.length);
  } else {
    const matchedClients = await clients.matchAll();
    console.log("matchedClients", matchedClients)
    return matchedClients.some(client => client.url.includes(chrome.runtime.id));
  }
}

function generateUUID() {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    const r = (Math.random() * 16) | 0;
    const v = c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3) | 0x8;
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}


offscreen.js:
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

// Registering this listener when the script is first executed ensures that the
// offscreen document will be able to receive messages when the promise returned
// by `offscreen.createDocument()` resolves.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessages);

// This function performs basic filtering and error checking on messages before
// dispatching the message to a more specific message handler.
async function handleMessages(message) {
  // Return early if this message isn't meant for the offscreen document.
  
  if (message.target !== 'offscreen') {
    return false;
  }
  console.log("received message in offscreen:",message)
  // Dispatch the message to an appropriate handler.
  switch (message.type) {
    case 'add-exclamationmarks-to-headings':
      addExclamationMarksToHeadings(message.data);
      break;
    default:
      console.warn(`Unexpected message type received: '${message.type}'.`);
      return false;
  }
}

function addExclamationMarksToHeadings(htmlString) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const document = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
  document
    .querySelectorAll('h1')
    .forEach((heading) => (heading.textContent = heading.textContent + '!!!'));
  
  sendToBackground(
    'add-exclamationmarks-result',
    document.documentElement.outerHTML
  );
  
}

function sendToBackground(type, data) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type,
    target: 'background',
    data
  });
  console.log("sended message to background: ",type, data)
}


the output:

Issues:
When checking for existing contexts with chrome.runtime.getContexts, the contexts array is empty, even though the offscreen document has been created and is functioning.
The offscreen document is able to process the messages and send back results correctly, but the service worker logs indicate that it can't find the offscreen document context when trying to close it.
Questions:
Why is chrome.runtime.getContexts returning an empty array even though the offscreen document exists?
Is there a more reliable way to check for the existence of the offscreen document?
How can I ensure that the offscreen document is properly closed after processing all HTML contents?
Thank you for your assistance!

As explained elsewhere the problem is in documentUrls: [OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT_PATH], which is not a URL, so either remove this line or use chrome.runtime.getURL(OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT_PATH).
Anyway, Google's sample is unnecessarily overcomplicated and demonstrates an anti-pattern of using a separate listener for messages where the proper solution is to use sendResponse.
Everything can simplified without any loss of functionality. You can also send all strings in one message, the size limit is 64MB.
// background.js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async () => {
  await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
    url: '/offscreen.html',
    reasons: ['DOM_PARSER'],
    justification: 'MV3 requirement',
  }).catch(e => {
    if (e.message !== 'Only a single offscreen document may be created.') throw e;
  });
  const res = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'add-exclamationmarks-to-headings',
    data: [
      '<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World 1</h1></body></html>',
      '<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World 2</h1></body></html>',
    ],
  });
  console.log(res);
  await chrome.offscreen.closeDocument();
});

// offscreen.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg.type === 'add-exclamationmarks-to-headings') {
    sendResponse(addExclamationMarksToHeadings(msg.data));
  }
});

function addExclamationMarksToHeadings(htmls) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  return htmls.map(html => {
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    for (const el of doc.querySelectorAll('h1')) el.append('!!!');
    return doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
  });
}

Note that chrome messaging in Chrome is limited to 64MB and JSON types (string, number, boolean, null, and arrays/objects consisting of the listed types). To send data types like Blob or typed arrays or overcome the 64MB limit you can use navigator.serviceWorker messaging, example.
